# Performance of background-canvas vs. regular canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, safari, webkit

A while back webkit (and thus Safari) began to support CSS canvas-backgrounds for elements (Source: http://www.webkit.org/blog/176/css-canvas-drawing/).

This could greatly simplify the creation of games and multimedia, in that you dont need to inject a canvas-tag into a DIV (for instance), but simply hook into the background of the DIV directly. Something like this perhaps:

```
<div id="gameview"
style="background: -webkit-canvas(myscreen); width: 320px; height: 480px;">
</div>

<script>
    var target = document.getElementById("gameview");
    var wd = target.clientWidth;
    var hd = target.clientHeight;
    var context =  document.getCSSCanvasContext("2d", "myscreen", wd, hd);
    /* draw stuff here */
</script>
```

I was wondering, are there any speed penalties involved in this? In theory i think drawing to a background canvas should be faster than drawing to a canvas tag, especially if the target element is empty.

Have anyone tested this for high-speed demos or games?

Comment: I just tested it. It turns out that the background view is not "live". It is rendered once and simply used as a background. The only way to force a repaint is to re-size the context. In short, this cant be used for games.

Comment: Background `canvas` appears to be as "live" as the usual one. See [a Snake game](http://jsfiddle.net/RpsZq/) (tested in Chrome).

Comment: With "live" i mean, that the graphics context is not drawn offscreen (internally by the browser code) and then blitted to the browser's main device context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test.php:11Regular Canvas 606
test.php:20Background Canvas 449
test.php:11Regular Canvas 516
test.php:20Background Canvas 483
```

Regular seems to underperform compared to background canvas in my tests on chrome in linux debian, heres the code used  ( also added to http://jsfiddle.net/hDPVr/ )

```
<div style="width:300; height:200; background: -webkit-canvas(test_canvas); "></div>
<canvas id="canvas" style="width:300; height:200;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var regular_timer = new Date().getTime() ;
    for( var i = 0; i<100000; i++ ){
    context.fillRect( 0,0,10,10);
    }
    console.log( 'Regular Canvas', regular_timer - (new Date().getTime()) )



    var context = document.getCSSCanvasContext('2d', 'test_canvas', 300, 200); 
    var background_timer = new Date().getTime() ;
    for( var i = 0; i<100000; i++ ){
    context.fillRect( 0,0,10,10);
    }
    console.log( 'Background Canvas', background_timer - (new Date().getTime()) )

</script>
```

So the only thing that I did for testing is fillRect, but it's still at least 10% better in some cases

Answer (score 3):

According to [my tests](http://jsfiddle.net/2KPzt/) (also run [in reversed order](http://jsfiddle.net/pm6mv/)), original `canvas` element is slightly but consistently slower than the background `canvas`.

Chromium 17 draws a chess-board 10000 times in:

- **~470 ms on the background canvas**
- **~520 ms on a `canvas` element**

Safari 5 shows similar dynamics.

Try setting the number of iterations to 100000, results should be consistent with the above.

---

### Update half a year later

We tried the background canvas approach in one project (as an attempt for a minor optimization), and the results were dramatically opposite to our expectations. The whole thing (two layers: one – a `div` with background canvas, the other – a regular canvas) became *marginally slower*. In fact, **when we introduced the background canvas, the app became slow as hell**. Tested in Chrome 21.

I definitely *would not* vouch for the background canvas to be faster in *all* situations.

Comment: Very interesting - any idea why background canvas is faster?

Comment: @AshleysBrain, I *guess*, because background isn't part of the DOM-tree. Also, [it's not scaling the bitmap](http://jsfiddle.net/2KPzt/1/) when you change its container's size. Someone who knows C++ might take a look at WebKit's source, maybe.

Comment: I would guess that it's because it doesnt force an immediate redraw. It's by nature an offscreen DIB (device independent bitmap) and will only be updated as part of the invalidation of the window. So when you draw X number of times to it, the window eliminates the update because it happens to quickly.